# I want to have different warning messages on select of radio buttons in JSF

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I have a scenario where there are multiple radio buttons for different status like **Active**, **Inactive**, **Pending**.

If I change the status from Active to Inactive it should popup a warning message. Similarly on selecting other radio buttons it should have different warning message.

Getting the `radioButtons` as `ListofStatus`

```
    <h:selectOneRadio id="statusList" value="#{Bean.billProgram.billProgramStatus}">
            <f:selectItems value="#{Bean.statusList}" />
    </h:selectOneRadio>
```

Any Idea how to do it. I am new to JSF.I tried in JS but didn't worked. Maybe it will be done in `ManagedBean` side.

Comment: Where do you display messages - on `<h:message(s)>`? Are you talking about different severity levels? You could define different severity levels such as `FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO`, `FacesMessage.SEVERITY_WARN`, `FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR`, `FacesMessage.SEVERITY_FATAL` and if necessary, you could also override specific CSS classes like `infoClass`, `warnClass`, `errorClass`, `fatalClass` and similarly, the corresponding styles like `infoStyle`, `warnStyle`, `errorStyle`, `fatalStyle`.

Answer (score 1):

For this make a ajax call on selectOneRadio. And on that ajax listener you can add the `FacesMessage`.

For this you can use primefaces. Here is [reference link](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/message/growl.xhtml)

**xhtml:**

```
<p:growl id="growl" showDetail="true" sticky="true" />  

<h:selectOneRadio id="statusList" value="#{Bean.billProgram.billProgramStatus}">
    <f:selectItems value="#{Bean.statusList}" />
    <p:ajax event="valueChange" update="growl" listener="#{listenerView.someMethod}" />
</h:selectOneRadio>
```

**Backing bean**

```
public void someMethod(AjaxBehaviorEvent event) {        
    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();  
    if(billProgram.billProgramStatus.equalIgnoreCase("Active")){               
        context.addMessage(null, new FacesMessage("Active",  "Active Detail") );     
    } else if(billProgram.billProgramStatus.equalIgnoreCase("Inactive")){
        context.addMessage(null, new FacesMessage("Inactive", "Inactive Detail"));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but next time please take a little more time to format it correctly.

Comment: Old click value will be in bean but how to keep the new click value?

Comment: Whenever you click on new value it will be automatically updated by new one, when you see on your bean it will be new one.